# Is it okay to use my Raspberry pi3 in low power?

Tags: power, power-supply

My raspberry always flashes the lightning icon and there's a warning a saying that. Is it okay to use my Raspberry pi on that condition?
Can it damage the raspberry?
I don't have an official power supply
I currently use my phone charger

Answer (score 2):

Actual hardware damage is very unlikely. The real risk is data loss: you can't trust your system to store data reliably, be it on the SD card, or an external storage such as USB thumb drives.

It's probably not a big problem if you just want to learn a bit of Linux. The moment you try to use the Pi in an actual project, it becomes a problem. You'll likely have strange unexpected failures no one else has (so not solvable by a Google search), which can waste a lot of your time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how low the voltage falls.

The Pi itself runs on lower voltages generated by an on-board regulator so should be OK.
Peripherals may have problems.